# POST error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to create a new row in "Category" table in MySQL database through JSON send by my Android app. The server side coding is done in RubyOnRails. But I am getting Uninitialised constant error on server side. The error is as below

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant CategoryController):
```

My rotues.rb file is

```
ROMS::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories

  resources :projects

  get "category/new"

  get "category/index"

  get "category/show"

  get "category_controller/index"

  get "category_controller/show"

  post "category/create"
```

I have given category/create in the URL for sending JSON. My CategoryController class is as below:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @category }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  # GET /categories/new.json
  def new
    @category = Category.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @category }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @category, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /categories/1
  # PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure what needs to initialize to create a row with my values in table. Please advise. Also please suggest if I need to parse JSON at server side in order to create a new row. I read that this is handled by ROR but not sure.

Since I am a complete newbie in ROR, apologies if this sounds a basic question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller code you have named it 'CategoriesController'. But In the routes it is expecting 'CategoryController'. Try correcting it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Actually I created Controller class through generate scaffold so it was created that ways. Anyways I changed my routes file to post "categories/create" , it was initially post "category/create". Also changed category to categories in my URL. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
get "category/new"

  get "category/index"

  get "category/show"

  get "category_controller/index"

  get "category_controller/show"

  post "category/create"
```

You can have `resources :categories` in your controller.

upon `rake routes`, you will get following route

```
   categories GET    /categories(.:format)          categories#index
              POST   /categories(.:format)          categories#create
 new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)      categories#new
edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format) categories#edit
     category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)      categories#show
              PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)      categories#update
              DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)      categories#destroy
```

And yes, you are rendering json in correct format in side the categories controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems quite helpful.